# Checking if an SSH tunnel is up and running

Tags: linux, perl, telnet, ssh-tunnel

I have a perl script which, when destilled a bit, looks like this:

```
my $randport = int(10000 + rand(1000));          # Random port as other scripts like this run at the same time
my $localip = '192.168.100.' . ($port - 4000);   # Don't ask... backwards compatibility
system("ssh -NL $randport:$localip:23 root\@$ip -o ConnectTimeout=60 -i somekey &");    # create the tunnel in the background

sleep 10;       # Give the tunnel some time to come up

# Create the telnet object
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet(
        Timeout =>      10,
        Host    =>      'localhost',
        Port    =>      $randport,
        Telnetmode =>   0,
        Errmode =>      \&fail,
);

# SNIPPED... a bunch of parsing data from $telnet
```

The thing is that the target $ip is on a link with very unpredictable bandwidth, so the tunnel might come up right away, it might take a while, it might not come up at all. So a sleep is necessary to give the tunnel some time to get up and running.

So the question is: How can i test if the tunnel is up and running? 10 seconds is a really undesirable delay if the tunnel comes up straight away. Ideally, i would like to check if it's up and continue with creating the telnet object once it is, to a maximum of, say, 30 seconds.

**Edit:** Ping doesn't help me mouch, as the remote end of the tunnel is generally up, but with a very high amount of packetloss

**Solved:** Extrapolating from the tip suggested by mikebabcock, `sleep 10` has been replaced with this block which works like a charm:

```
my $starttime = time();
while (1)
{
    # Check for success
    if (system("nc -dzw10 localhost $randport > /dev/null") == 0) { last }

    # Check for timeout
    if (time() > $starttime + 30) { &fail() }

    # 250ms delay before recheck
    select (undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: Since you're using the `Net::Telnet` module, have you tried using the `open` call and testing for success? I'm no Telnet expert, but that's what I would probably try if it were me...

Comment: I might do that if there's not a simple way of testing: retry until success if time_spend_trying < 30 seconds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use netcat -- often `nc` on Linux systems:

```
nc -dvzw10 ${HOSTNAME} 23
```

Works for me, with a response like:

```
Connection to ${HOSTNAME} 23 port [tcp/telnet] succeeded!
```

It also returns 0 on success, and is happy with a simple connection after which it goes away.

- -d means not to read anything from the keyboard side
- -v means to be verbose (turn this off in a script)
- -z means to disconnect after making the connection
- -w10 means to wait up to 10 seconds, otherwise give up

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=nc+-dvzw10

Comment: @alper the explanation of each command-line option is already in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate a ping to your ssh server and if it works fine the ssh tunnel is up

```bash
# only a ping sample :-D
if !  ping -c 1 192.168.101.9; then
    echo "ping does not succeed"
else
    echo "ping succeed"
fi
```

Comment: ping doesn't help me much, as it generally has ~50% packetloss (this is tested beforehand, and believe it or not, it's acceptable down to 50%)

Comment: but it exit with success if the tunnel is up. The quality is a part of other communication levels

Comment: If you want a better quality to wait you can parse the ping output. But will you disconnect if the quality is to bad?

Answer (score 0):

I think fping might be better then the usual ping, more script friendly.

fping -t 60000 [your server]

should try to connect to the server 60seconds before giving up
Something like

```
if(fping -t 60000 [your server]) {
execute desired code;
} else {
execute this script again to rerun;;
}
```

I think you get the idea even if the coding isn't real.